# Why XHTML markup does not generate parsing error?

Tags: html, xhtml

I started learning the basics of HTML and I have studied differences between XHTML and HTML. I have noticed XHTML is much stricter. Consider below markup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
   <title>Every document must have a title</title>
 </head> 
<body>
  <b><p>hey</b></p><br>
</body>
</html>
```

I have not properly nested the tags and `<br>` is not properly closed in XHTML but it does not raise any parsing error and when I have saved the file as `test.xhtml` then it raised parsing error. So how to actually create XHTML files and also how to use XHTML in HTML5? and could anyone explain me that files saved with `.xhtml` are XHTML files and with `.html` are treated as HTML files?

Iam using google chrome. I understand the differences but unable to view practically in the browser. Could anyone help me figuring this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most web browsers have XML and HTML parsers. These use different rules.

In general, the rules they follow are:

- If the document has one of various XML content-types and the document in in the XHTML name space: Use the XML parser
- If the document has a `text/html` content-type then use the HTML parser
- If the document is loaded from a local file and has a `.xhtml` file extension, then treat it as having the content-type `application/xhtml+xml`
- If the document is loaded from a local file and has a `.html` file extension, then treat it as having the content-type `text/html`

Comment: I don't think they've ever stopped doing that. What older browsers (IE specifically) did differently was simply fail to recognize the XML content-type altogether. In fact, this is the first time I've heard about browsers falling back to the HTML parser.

Comment: So there is no way of making .html file parse with XHTML parser?

Comment: @BoltClock — Huh. I've just been able to get a failed error. There was a big fuss a few years ago when Opera introduced the fallback. I thought everyone had followed suit.

Comment: @user3205479 — Tell your server to give `.html` files an XHTML content-type.